# Cython way slower than corresponding C++ function

Tags: python, c++, numpy, cython

I'm confused with which the Cython C++ compilation.
I have an algorithm that I have implemented in C++, I either call it from C++ or from python through a Cython wrapper.
The wrapping part of the code takes a negligible amount of time, 
but the algorithm runs ~10x faster if I don't use Cython.

The Cython running time is very similar to the C++ time without optimization.

I compile my program like this:

```
setup(ext_modules = cythonize(Extension(
           "max_depth_cpp", 
           sources=["cpp/wrap.pyx", "cpp/count_inliers.cpp", 
                    "cpp/max_depth.cpp", "cpp/misc.cpp", "cpp/solver.cpp", 
                    "cpp/vec3.cpp" , "cpp/wrapper.cpp"], 
           language="c++",          
           extra_compile_args=["-O3","-std=c++17"],
           extra_link_args = ["-std=c++17"]
      )))
```

Removing the -O3 option does not changing the running time.

`wrap.pyx`

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np  # for np.ndarray
np.import_array() #verk important (seg faults)

cdef extern from "wrapper.h":
    void wrapper(double*, double*, int,  double, double*)


    cpdef max_depth_cpp(np_v1, np_v2, eps):
        cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=2, mode='c'] v1 = np_v1
        cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=2, mode='c'] v2 = np_v2
        cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=1, mode='c'] t
        t = np.zeros(3, dtype=np.double)

        wrapper(&v1[0,0], &v2[0,0], len(v1), eps, &t[0])
        return t
```

`wrapper.cpp`

```
#include "wrapper.h"
#include "solver.h"

void wrapper(double* v1_in, double* v2_in, int N,  double eps, double* t){
    solver(v1_in, v2_in, N, eps, t);   //changes t
}
```

Solver just calls my calls my C++ method. It copies all the data from the numpy arrays first, but that takes very little of the total time

Comment: "The running time is also very similar to when I run the function as a pure C++ function, without optimization." - do you mean "a pure Python function"? However, this seems like the sort of thing that depends entirely on all the code that you're not showing.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I added more information. I timed the function call and it takes like 10x longer to run it like this, than with normal c++

Comment: I'd guess this might be to do with multithreading, but I don't think it's possible for me to be certain

Comment: can you share exact timings and would love to see how it was measured

Comment: Hi I'm having the same issue, calling C++ code from a cython wrapper is much slower than calling it with the same inputs from C++, seems to be something to do with compiler optimizations? I am looking at a single thread by the way. Any progress on this?